# How to find the last element in an array in unix?

Tags: arrays, unix, if-statement, ksh

How can i find the last element in an array in unix? I need find the last element in an array to do an `if-statement`:

```
    if [ #last_array ];
    then
     #Do something
    fi
```

How can i do it? Can i put only one parameter in the if? I want only the last array to do something

Comment: What do you mean with last array? Can you give some examples?

Comment: i found this: `echo ${ARR1[@]:(-1)}`. Will print the last element in the array.. Now i want do something like "if is the last element do something" is it possible?

Comment: So you mean `last element of an array`, not `last array`, that sounded weird.

Comment: yeah sorry, now edit the request.

Comment: `echo ${ARR1[@]:(-1)}` seems not work :(

Comment: It is clear what you want but depending on the context can have different approaches. Are you looping through the array and want to indicate when you are done? Are you comparing all elements of the array? Try to contextualize so we can answer properly.

Comment: i need these conditions to make an insert..and now i have to write that if it is the last element of array this element will insert without "`,`" at the end.. The others yes (but doesn't metter this part).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that something like that could make it. It is not very nice, I know, but cannot think in other good ways:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=("hello" "bye" "another" "word")
i=0

num_words=${#a[@]}
echo "there are $num_words words"

for word in "${a[@]}"
do
        let i=i+1
        echo $i $word
        if [ $i -eq $num_words ]; then
                echo "last word!"
        fi
done
```

#### Test

```
$ ./test
there are 4 words
1 hello
2 bye
3 another
4 word
last word!
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ set -A arr 1 2 3 4 5
$ let LAST_ELEMENT=${#arr[*]}-1
$ echo ${arr[$LAST_ELEMENT]}
```